# returnStdout doesn't works when calls a remote sh

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to get the response by returnStdout from a remote machine when i call a script, but I can't get ip value, I'm using this code in groovy declarative.

- IP_EC2 var is the host's ip where the code upload_ip.sh will be executed
- CRED_MACHINE var is the ssh cred name to connect to the machine

the code is below

```
    sh ("""
    cat <<EOF > upload_ip.sh
             #!/bin/bash

             IP=1.1.1.1

             echo "\\\$IP"
         EOF""")


withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${CRED_MACHINE}", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
    IP=sh (returnStdout: true, script: "cat upload_ip.sh | ssh -i ${keyfile} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=30 ubuntu@${IP_EC2}")
}
```

Comment: should not the closing `EOF` be at the beginning of line and have newline after it?